# Creating squares with ggplot (what is the height of my y-axis when using categorical variable in y-scale?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidy

I have data like this:

```
class date       color  
   <chr> <date>     <chr>  
 1 two   2021-01-21 #00FF00
 2 two   2021-02-01 #83FF83
 3 two   2021-02-11 #CDFFCD
 4 two   2021-02-21 #7BFF7B
 5 two   2021-03-03 #94FF94
 6 two   2021-03-13 #F6FFF6
 7 two   2021-03-23 #EEFFEE
 8 two   2021-04-02 #C5FFC5
 9 two   2021-04-12 #8BFF8B
10 two   2021-04-22 #F6FFF6
11 one   2021-01-21 #00FF00
12 one   2021-02-01 #83FF83
13 one   2021-02-11 #CDFFCD
14 one   2021-02-21 #7BFF7B
15 one   2021-03-03 #94FF94
16 one   2021-03-13 #F6FFF6
17 one   2021-03-23 #EEFFEE
18 one   2021-04-02 #C5FFC5
19 one   2021-04-12 #8BFF8B
20 one   2021-04-22 #EEFFEE
```

You can reproduce it with this dput:

```
structure(list(class = c("two", "two", "two", "two", "two", "two", 
"two", "two", "two", "two", "one", "one", "one", "one", "one", 
"one", "one", "one", "one", "one"), date = structure(c(18648, 
18659, 18669, 18679, 18689, 18699, 18709, 18719, 18729, 18739, 
18648, 18659, 18669, 18679, 18689, 18699, 18709, 18719, 18729, 
18739), class = "Date"), color = c("#00FF00", "#83FF83", "#CDFFCD", 
"#7BFF7B", "#94FF94", "#F6FFF6", "#EEFFEE", "#C5FFC5", "#8BFF8B", 
"#F6FFF6", "#00FF00", "#83FF83", "#CDFFCD", "#7BFF7B", "#94FF94", 
"#F6FFF6", "#EEFFEE", "#C5FFC5", "#8BFF8B", "#EEFFEE")), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -20L), groups = structure(list(
    class = c("one", "two"), .rows = structure(list(11:20, 1:10), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))
```

What I wanted to create was something like this "github"-ish look. So I wanted to create square tiles over the entire range of the dates. For each class (one and two). The date-range is the same.

So I, for example, want that square to have the height == width such that it fills the entire width of the plot. So I did this:

```
   ggplot() +
     geom_tile(data = df,
               aes(x = date,
                   y = class,
                   fill = color),
               show.legend = F) +
     scale_fill_identity()
```

The result is this:

[image]

I do not understand what `y=class` exactly does. Where does it place the `class` variable on the y-axis. Assuming that it uses the range from 1 / (however many categories), I gave it a height of 0.5 (what units?) like this:

```
   ggplot() +
     geom_tile(data = df,
               aes(x = date,
                   y = class,
                   height=.5,
                   fill = color),
               show.legend = F) +
     scale_fill_identity()
```

The result is the (better, yet not exactly what I want)

[image]

So I removed the `height=.5` and figured that I should get it done with the `coord_equal` argument. I just don't know how. Simply taking away the fixed height and add a `coord_equal` like this:

```
   ggplot() +
     geom_tile(data = df,
               aes(x = date,
                   y = class,
                   fill = color),
               show.legend = F) +
     scale_fill_identity()  +
     coord_equal()
```

Produces this :(

[image]

So if anyone has any idea on how to get this done I'd highly appreciate it:)

Comment: Do you have any representation of the expected output?

Comment: Yeah I'm sorry I was thinking about that, but no I don't:/

Comment: But It's like in the second plot, just instead of rectangles I'd like squares (and minus this gap after the first rectangle;)

Comment: What is a ' "github"-ish look '? Can you provide a link ?

Comment: https://github.com/torvalds ;)

Comment: The height on the y-axis between two categories is exactly 1. Also, the first discrete label has the position 1. Under the hood, discrete values are mapped with roughly this function `function(x) match(x, unique(x))`.

Answer (score 1):

The key to answering OP's question is to fix the aspect ratio of your plot.  The images OP shows are all with an aspect ratio that probably matches the direct output of what is in RStudio or the console (default for the particular graphics device OP is using).  To fix the issue, you want to either change the `width=` and `height=` of your graphics output or save file with something like `ggsave('filename.png', width=..., height=...)`, or to **fix the ratio based on the data**.

You can play around with a particular number for width/height and fix the coordinates using `coord_fixed()`, but I prefer to do this programmatically to allow for an expansion of any data.

Based on the data OP shared, the ratio should be approximated by the number of observations in the dataset (number of days) and the number of unique values for `df$class`.  You also may want to tweak some elements of `geom_tile()` and control the panel space outside the tiles via `scale_*` functions and the `expand=` argument.

Heree's the code:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x=date, y=class, fill=color)) +
  geom_tile(height=0.8, width=7) +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  scale_x_date(expand=expansion(mult=c(0.05))) +
  scale_y_discrete(expand=expansion(mult=c(0.7))) +
  coord_fixed(ratio = nrow(df)/length(unique(df$class)))
```

And the output:

[image]

You can use `ggsave(..., width=... and height=...)` to fix the empty space around the plot if you wish.

Note that I came to select `width=` and `height=` values for `geom_tile()` here more or less by trial-and-error.  Height makes sense (since as @teunbrand pointed out, discrete values are separated by ~1 unit).  For width, I figured since dates are probably mapped as 1 day = 1 unit and there were 4 in a month here... each block was about 7 days.  It seemed to work out well.