# ggplot2 geom_linerange remove whitespace between rows

Tags: r, ggplot2

Am attempting to create a plot similar to a strip chart recorder showing outage data.  Outage Severity is Major and Minor.  Plot has a large amount of vertical white space between the two rows and before and after that I would like to remove to create a compact two-row chart.

dataframe is:

```
> head(dfsub)
                StartDateTime                 EndDateTime Outage.DUR Outage.Severity
1 2021-07-01T00:23:33.0000000 2021-07-01T00:25:26.0000000  1.8833333           Minor
2 2021-07-01T00:25:26.0000000 2021-07-01T00:31:33.0000000  6.1166667           Major
3 2021-07-01T00:31:33.0000000 2021-07-01T00:40:34.0000000  9.0166667           Major
4 2021-07-01T00:40:34.0000000 2021-07-01T00:42:57.0000000  2.3833333           Minor
5 2021-07-01T00:42:57.0000000 2021-07-01T00:43:49.0000000  0.8666667           Minor
6 2021-07-01T00:43:49.0000000 2021-07-01T00:45:35.0000000  1.7666667           Minor
```

R Code I am running

```
ggplot(dfsub) +
  geom_linerange(aes(y = Outage.Severity, 
                     xmin = StartDateTime,
                     xmax = EndDateTime,
                     colour = as.factor(Outage.Severity)
                     ),
                 show.legend = FALSE,
                 size = 50) +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("red", "yellow")) +
  theme(legend.position = "none") +
  theme_test()
```

generates this plot
[image: linerange plot - lots of whitespace]

Comment: Convert `StartDateTime` and `End..` to `POSIXt` columns, otherwise it is categorical (see your x-axis). If you don't know how to do this, see [`?as.POSIXt`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/as.POSIXlt.html) for its arguments and [`?strptime`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html) for the `%`-codes to use within `format=`. If that isn't enough, SO has tons of questions and answers resolving every aspect of the function that I've ever witnessed.

Comment: It may not seem like it at first, but [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70801612/creating-squares-with-ggplot-what-is-the-height-of-my-y-axis-when-using-categor/70808181#70808181) for what is basically the same question.   Simply put, your have a ton of whitespace because you're looking at something with vastly different resolution in x and y dimensions using a 16:9 or something similar aspect ratio.  The aspect ratio of your plot does not match the ratio of observations noted on the plot.  Set window size, output size, or plot aspect ratio (i.e. `coord_fixed(ratio=)`.

Comment: Thank-you both for your help with this.  I had completely ignored how my display was effecting the view.  And the time axis format error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two suggestions.

1. You didn't ask about this, but your x-axis is broken, using time (which is a continuous thing) in a categorical sense. Note that R and `ggplot2` are treating the current columns as *strings* not *timestamps*. This is easily resolved:

   ```r
   dfsub[c("StartDateTime", "EndDateTime")] <-
     lapply(dfsub[c("StartDateTime", "EndDateTime")], as.POSIXct, format="%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%OS", tz="UTC")
   ```
2. I don't think you're going to get the fine control over blank space between the reds and yellows using `geom_linerange`, I suggest `geom_rect` as an option. With that, remove `size=`, and we'll need to control `ymin=` and `ymax=`. This benefits from setting `Outage.Severity` to a factor; while not completely necessary, it's common for this work to then come back with *"how do I change the order of the y-axis categories?"*, for which the only (sane) response is to convert them to factors and control their `levels=`. We also need to add `fill=`, which `geom_linerange` did not need.

   ```r
   dfsub$Outage.Severity <- factor(dfsub$Outage.Severity) # add 'levels=' if you want to control the order
   ```

   From here, knowing that categorical data are plotted on integers, we'll fill the gap between them by extending their rectangles +/- 0.48 (arbitrary, but should likely be close to but not at/beyond 0.5).

   ```r
   ggplot(dfsub) +
     geom_rect(aes(ymin = as.numeric(Outage.Severity)-0.48,
                   ymax = as.numeric(Outage.Severity)+0.48,
                   xmin = StartDateTime,
                   xmax = EndDateTime,
                   colour = Outage.Severity,
                   fill = Outage.Severity),
               show.legend = FALSE) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = unique(as.numeric(dfsub$Outage.Severity)), labels = unique(dfsub$Outage.Severity)) +
     scale_color_manual(values = c("Major"="red", "Minor"="yellow")) +
     scale_fill_manual(values = c("Major"="red", "Minor"="yellow")) +
     theme(legend.position = "none") +
     theme_test()
   ```

[image]